# Why do all browsers' user agents start with "Mozilla/"?

Tags: user-agent

All popular browsers' user agent strings, even Internet Explorer's, start with `Mozilla/`. Why is this the case?

Comment: User agents have been used to tell web servers “**I’m not a random crap; I _also_ support features that these support.** Please do not discriminate against me.” Hence the user agent of a browser having all others in it.

Answer (score 367, accepted):

It is a [long and sad story](http://webaim.org/blog/user-agent-string-history/).

In summary:

1. Mozilla browser gets released, with User-Agent `Mozilla/1.0 (Win3.1)`. It is publicly renamed to Netscape, but in its User-Agent it keeps its original name .
2. Internet Explorer is released. It spoofs Netscape by starting its User-Agent with `Mozilla/` because web servers were routinely browser sniffing and serving pages with frames - a feature supported by both Netscape and IE, but not other browsers of the era - to Netscape only.
3. Over time, Gecko, Konqueror, Opera, Safari and Chrome each decide to similarly spoof the User-Agent of some previous browser in order to manipulate browser-sniffing web pages into correctly understanding their browser's features. As part of this spoofing, all the browsers start their User-Agents with `Mozilla/`, like the browsers before them had done. Plenty of other nonsense also results, like modern Chrome's User-Agent simultaneously claiming to be Mozilla, Chrome, Safari, and 'like Gecko'.

Comment: Like the link, but also check out Mike Mu's wikipedia link for more info.

Comment: Note that the "Mozilla" here is **not** the current open-source project of that name, but the original codename of Netscape, thought to refer to "Mosaic Killer". The codename was reused many years later for the open source project, whose rendering engine is the "Gecko" mentioned here.

Comment: And here we are in 2015, still perpetuating the stupidity. MS Edge's user agent string is `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Safari/537.36 Edge/12.1`.

Comment: No wonder it's hard to do browser detection, they're all pretending to be one another!

Comment: The browser wars weren't without casualties.

Comment: If `userAgent` String is such a mess, then, why is it not deprecated and/or removed?

Comment: @MelvinAbraham It is still useful because not all requests come from browsers. You may need to look at browser vs. server (API) traffic for example

Comment: Bonus point for the linked article, quite hilarious. "And there was much rejoicing"

Comment: What does "frame" mean? Is it `iframe`?

Comment: Nope, "frame" refers to Frameset. A now-deprecated way of making UIs with HTML and duct tape. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/frameset

Answer (score 34):

I think it had to do with: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent#User_agent_spoofing

Back in the early days, Netscape (code named Mozilla) was the main rival of IE, and they wanted to prevent being rejected by sites rejecting browsers other than Netscape.

Answer (score 17):

As mentioned by @Jason "Its a long story". Summing that story up "its just every browser pretends to be Mozilla"

After trying everything, I have finally used: http://www.useragentstring.com/

You can use the above website to get the formatted user agent and OS. 
They have an [API](http://www.useragentstring.com/?uas=Mozilla/5.0%20%28Windows%20NT%206.1%29%20AppleWebKit/537.36%20%28KHTML,%20like%20Gecko%29%20Chrome/27.0.1453.110%20Safari/537.36&getJSON=all) which you can use directly...

Comment: Pedantic correction: every browser, including Mozilla, pretends to be Netscape, whose user-agent began Mozilla. The fact that the codename was reused just adds to the confusion.

Comment: Mozilla and Firefox codebase was originally part of Netscape though. That's why many of Firefox internal APIs has "ns" as its prefix.

Answer (score 10):

Reason for this are the infamous **browser wars**.

In short - browsers started to pretend to be some other browser, because some websites served content based on which browser asked for it and they also wanted content meant for other browsers.

I find it surprising it still haven't been solved to this day. Since `userAgent` can't be safely removed for legacy reasons, why some new feature clearly identifying a browser wasn't introduced? Yes, most of the time you don't need browser detection, but rather a feature detection, but it is not built-in JS neither!

Answer (score 4):

Because that's how Netscape identified itself, and Microsoft wanted to work with sites that would detect Netscape and reject anything else.

Answer (score 2):

*Mozilla/5.0 is the general token that says the browser is Mozilla compatible, and is common to almost every browser today.*
for more detail [click here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent/Firefox)

Comment: This is a little misleading - note that the "Mozilla" being referred to is actually the Mozilla (Mosaic-killer) browser, which was rebranded to Netscape before release (and which most readers have probably never heard of by its original name) - *not* Mozilla the non-profit free software community that's still around today.