# Why does navigator.appCodeName return Mozilla?

Tags: javascript, browser

The following JavaScript code returns "Mozilla" on all browsers. Why?

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 document.write("Browser CodeName: " + navigator.appCodeName);
 </script>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do all browsers' user agents start with "Mozilla/"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1114254/why-do-all-browsers-user-agents-start-with-mozilla)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Short answer: Because people thought that user agent detection (instead of [feature (AKA object) detection](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/support.html)) was a good idea, so browser vendors started lying in order to compensate.

Long answer: [History of the browser user-agent string](http://webaim.org/blog/user-agent-string-history/)

Comment: the user agent string was a complete mess, and near useless, and everyone pretended to be everyone else, and confusion abounded.

Answer (score 11):

Many years ago, developers used browser detection to reject other browsers, usually favouring Netscape Navigator (precursor to Mozilla and Firefox, also codenamed Mozilla). They tested for the string `'Mozilla'` in the user agent. Internet Explorer got angsty and decided to imitate Netscape so they could join in on the fun.

Answer (score 1):

That navigator.appCodeName based on useragent string and In IE's useragent string, there is Mozilla 4.0 or something, so thats why its display `Mozilla` for both.

Answer (score -2):

This property is kept only for `compatibility purposes`.

Please refer this page:

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorID/appCodeName
>   http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_nav_appcodename.asp

https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20709/can-anyone-tell-me-why-does-chrome-tell-it-is-mozilla-and-safari-also