# Office365 Addins - How to communicate between addin Windows

Tags: javascript, ms-office, powerpoint, office365, apps-for-office

I am working on an Office365 Javascript Content Addin for PowerPoint and am having trouble with messaging.

Unlike Word or Excel, it is likely multiple Add-ins will be used in one document. E.g. One on slide 3, one on slide 5.

I have 2 scenarios that are not working nicely.

- Using the Office365 webclient (works fine in native) - if something is changed
  in slideshow mode, this is not automatically reflected when returning to that
  slide in designer mode.
- Webclient and native - If a user logs out on one slide, I cannot get the add-ins on other slides to automatically log out as well.

*What I've tried so far:*

- Looked through the [Office.js](http://www.getcodesamples.com/src/ECFF3758/34EACEF4) file and [documentation](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/javascript-api-for-office).
- Investigated the [underlying tech](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32039841/what-browser-browser-engine-do-office-add-ins-use/32076794#comment62156029_32076794) so expected some standard html techniques to work.
- Tried both postMessage and using a [storage event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4079280/javascript-communication-between-browser-tabs-windows) (which worked in IE directly, but not when in PowerPoint).

I could impement a heartbeat or websockets, but would rather avoid hitting the server unnecessarily and and would like to keep things as simple as possible. Alternatively, I could put something in localstorage and use setInterval to check it, but that would add unnecessary background work and slow the application down.

Are there any 'good' ways of solving the above mentioned problems, or is the setInterval/localstorage check the only simple solution at the moment?

Comment: I have had to go with the setTimeout/localStorage option. 'setTimeout' is better than setInterval as setInterval in this case (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/729921/settimeout-or-setinterval). Not an ideal solution, but it works. Not going to close this question yet, as in a later version of the api, an event may be added that makes this possible (e.g. in line with @michael mainers response below).

Answer (score 2):

You could try using the [document.settings](http://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/shared/document.settings?product=powerpoint) property instead of localStorage. There is a settingsChanged event that might help you do what you're looking for. I've never used it before so let us know if it helps (or not).

The settingsChanged event is only available for Excel as of this post date.

Comment: Will give it a go. Thanks.

Comment: No joy for now. The method would be great, but it's only supported in Excel at the moment. http://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/shared/settings.addhandlerasync

Comment: That is unfortunate. You can voice your scenario through https://officespdev.uservoice.com/. Add a request for this feature at this location.

Answer (score 0):

Trawling through the documentation, it seems this sort of thing can be achieved using [refreshAsync](http://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/shared/settings.refreshasync).