# Unable to add browser in Visual Studio for Office App

Tags: visual-studio, office-js

Using Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 Update 3, I create a new project following these steps:

- File -> New -> Project -> Templates/Visual C#/ Office/SharePoint/Apps
- Choose **App for Office** (.NET Framework 4.5.2)
- In **Create app for Office** window, Check **Task pane** and do **Next**
- Check **Excel**, **PowerPoint** and **Word** and click **Finish**

After creating the solution, In **Solution Explorer** Window, Select the first project (manifest project) and look at the **Properties** Window.

If I click the **Start Action** drop down list, I can only see Chrome and Edge browsers (were installed before visual studio).

I have installed `FireFox` after visual studio and I'm not unable to add it to **Start Action** drop down list. I want to debug my Office App in FireFox as well.

How can I fix this issue?

[image]

Comment: I don't have any "App for Office" choice. Is this a special addin/template?

Comment: Try to install Microsoft Office Developer Tools Preview 2 for Visual Studio 2015 as suggested in https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/07/14/office-sharepoint-template-missing-in-visual-studio-2015/

Answer (score 3):

An Office add-in running in desktop Office, which it is where it runs when you are debugging it with Visual Studio on a Windows machine, uses **IE** under the hood. (For more info, see [what-browser-browser-engine-do-office-add-ins-use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32039841/what-browser-browser-engine-do-office-add-ins-use).) You can't change this. The Start Action setting has no effect. You are **always** using IE when you press F5. In particular, the Start Action of the manifest project is irrelevant because the manifest doesn't run or get loaded into a browser.

If you want to test the add-in in Office Online, you can [sideload it](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/testing/sideload-office-add-ins-for-testing), and when you run it, it will use whatever browser you used to open Office Online.

Comment: The instructions for the developer tools (F12) of all the major browsers say that you can set breakpoints in the tools. I've never tried it, however. I don't know whether it would work for the IFrame in which the add-in runs when it is running on Office Online; but it would be easy enough try it out.

Comment: It does work.  You just have to find your code which can be kind of tricky to do because of the iFrame.  adding a "debugger;" to your code can help with this.