# Cannot debug add-in using F12Chooser in 1903

Tags: windows-10, apps-for-office

As of the update to 1903 Office Add-ins started using Edge as the browser. It looks like this has broken the ability to attach the F12Chooser debugger to the browser session.

Is anyone else noticing this or has anyone been able to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

F12Chooser is for Internet Explorer. For Office-Add-ins with Edge use "Microsoft Edge DevTools":

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/debug-add-ins-using-f12-developer-tools-on-windows-10

Comment: Ah! Thank you - they have finally updated the docs. I will try this out tomorrow at work and accept if it's all good.