# why Chrome browser is giving 'mozilla' to navigator.appCodeName in console?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, mozilla

[image]

Why it isn't showing as 'chrome' for navigator.appCodeName ?
I know Mozilla and Chrome are different browsers.
Does anyone of you know this?

My observations for the navigator.appCodeName respone:

- Windows - Chrome : 'Mozilla' Ubuntu
- Chrome: 'mozilla' Ubuntu
- Mozilla FireFox: 'Mozilla'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does navigator.appCodeName return Mozilla?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2780652/why-does-navigator-appcodename-return-mozilla)

Comment: [navigator.appCodeName gives Mozilla](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2780667/11926970) read this

Comment: all (modern) browsers appCodeName is Mozilla because Mozilla is the one true browser