# Why does Internet Explorer (9) report "Mozilla" in UserAgent?

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, user-agent, history

Why does Internet Explorer has `Mozilla` in UserAgent?

In Firefox it's stating:

> Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:7.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/7.0.1

In Interner Explorer it's stating:

> Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; Tablet PC 2.0; .NET4.0E; .NET4.0C)

In some blogs/forums it's mentioned, that it is due to some historical reasons, but what's the reason?

It would be very helpful to know about it.

Comment: I ran into [Introduces IE9's User Agent String](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2010/03/23/introducing-ie9-s-user-agent-string.aspx) awhile ago which also has a "history" link - "Mozilla/x" appears to have been around circa Netscape 2.x!. It doesn't explain the Gecko/Firefox additions reported, however.

Comment: oops my typo mistake in IE user agent string..

Comment: I don't think that IE UserAgent you've provided is a correct one. "Gecko/20100101 Firefox/7.0.1" part is from other song.

Comment: The scary part is that IE9 is reporting that it is also a *"Tablet PC 2.0"!* - though I believe this comes from installation of Express-js.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why do Chrome and IE put "Mozilla 5.0" in the User-Agent they send to the server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5125438/why-do-chrome-and-ie-put-mozilla-5-0-in-the-user-agent-they-send-to-the-server)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why "Mozilla" string is present on all browser's User Agent?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1114254/why-mozilla-string-is-present-on-all-browsers-user-agent)

Answer (score 86, accepted):

this should do it:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mozilla

> When users visit a website (via a user agent such as a web browser), a
>   text string is generally sent to identify the user agent to the web
>   server. It is known as the "user agent string". The Netscape web
>   browser identified itself as "Mozilla/" followed by some
>   information about the operating system it was running on.
>
> Because the Netscape browser initially implemented many features not
>   available in other browsers and quickly came to dominate the market, a
>   number of web sites were designed to work, or work fully, only when
>   they detected an appropriate version of Mozilla in the user agent
>   string. Thus, competing browsers began to emulate ("cloak" or "spoof")
>   this string in order to also work with those sites. The earliest
>   example of this is Internet Explorer's use of a user agent string
>   beginning "Mozilla/ (compatible; MSIE ...", in order
>   to receive content intended for Netscape, its main rival at the time
>   of its development. This format of user agent string has since been
>   copied by other user agents, and persisted even after Internet
>   Explorer came to dominate the browser market.

wiki knows everything

also https://superuser.com/questions/113020/why-does-internet-explorer-calls-itself-mozilla