# Why do most browsers have "Mozilla" in their User Agent HTTP header field?

Tags: http, browser, user-agent

I've noted that in almost all browsers including Chrome, IE, and Firefox the user agent string has the word "Mozilla". What does it mean there? Does this mean that all of'em extend on the base core of Firefox from Mozilla?

Chrome:

```
   User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.22 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/25.0.1364.152 Safari/537.22
```

Firefox:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0
```

Comment: [This should help](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7976057/1291812). Mostly for compatibility with old websites.