# Browser detection based on User Agent

Tags: browser

I have the following user agent, picked up from a website log:

`Mozilla/5.0+(Linux;+Android+4.4.4;+Nexus+5+Build/KTU84P)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/37.0.2062.117+Mobile+Safari/537.36`

How do I know which device/browser - Both android and Apple are mentioned.
Browsers - both Chrome and Safari are mentioned here!

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It specifically mentions Nexus 5. Seems pretty clear that's Android. You got lucky, the device name was in the string.

The reason it mentions all of those is for compatibility purposes. If developers target specific devices by looking at the user agent string, then if you want your device to have all those features, you have to include the string so that it knows your device is also capable of the features of those devices.

For more info, see [Why “Mozilla” string is present on all browser's User Agent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1114254/why-mozilla-string-is-present-on-all-browsers-user-agent)?.