# Unable to get `User-Agent` properly from header

Tags: java, http, servlets, httprequest, servlet-filters

`Hi,

I am trying to get the user's browser information in my servlet filter. I used a simple code, see below.

```
String userAgent = request.getHeader("User-Agent");
```

User was using Google chrome, and what the above code printed is below.

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Safari/537.36
```

It printed the names of all the major browsers instead of getting the once the app is running. what is wrong here?

Comment: This is Chrome's user agent string.

Comment: On this [site](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/Chrome/) is a list of all user agent strings used by the different browsers.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1326928/how-can-i-get-client-infomation-such-as-os-and-browser for more help

Comment: Most modern browsers [spoof their identification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent#User_agent_spoofing) to let a server think that it is compatible to render the complex content. It's a long story. See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1114297/1122665) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is wrong here.

For example let us consider the returned string is

Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36

Then the explanation is

```
ChromeChrome 41.0.2228.0

Mozilla ==> 

MozillaProductSlice. Claims to be a Mozilla based user agent, which is only true for Gecko browsers like Firefox and Netscape. For all other user agents it means 'Mozilla-compatible'. In modern browsers, this is only used for historical reasons. It has no real meaning anymore

5.0 ==> Mozilla version

Windows NT 6.1  ==> Operating System Windows 7 

AppleWebKit  ==> The Web Kit provides a set of core classes to display web content in windows

537.36       ==> Web Kit build
KHTML        ==> Open Source HTML layout engine developed by the KDE project
like Gecko   ==> like Gecko...
Chrome  Name ==> Chrome
41.0.2228.0  ==> Chrome version
Safari       ==> Based on Safari
537.36       ==> Safari build

Description:    Free open-source web browser developed by Google. 
Chromium is the name of the open source project behind Google Chrome, released under the BSD license.
```

You can find more information in below link

http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/Chrome/

click on each link on the page to get more info