# Can anyone explain the fields in web server log data?

Tags: field, weblog

Can anyone tell me the fields' name in following web server log data?

```
85.214.57.164 - - [27/Mar/2008:22:46:36 -0400] "GET /LongDistance/ServicesAgreement.html?logo=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.antwerpsupporter.be%2Fsubscribe_2_me_to-delete%2Fsm%2Fexported_files1%2Fmosupoz%2Fadusa%2Fojafujo%2Faweji%2F HTTP/1.0" 404 374 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)"
85.214.57.164 - - [27/Mar/2008:22:46:36 -0400] "GET /LongDistance/ServicesAgreement.html?logo=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.math.science.cmu.ac.th%2Flms%2Flib%2Fadodb%2Fpear%2Fnoxifi%2Fezogan%2F HTTP/1.0" 404 374 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)"
85.214.57.164 - - [27/Mar/2008:22:46:37 -0400] "GET /LongDistance/ServicesAgreement.html?logo=http%3A%2F%2Fsans-packing.ru%2Fimg%2Fjipeqap%2Fehudute%2F HTTP/1.0" 404 374 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)"
```

**Explanation** -

I am aware of all other fields i.e.

```
client IP, 
Date, 
time, 
time zone, 
method, 
URL requested, 
protocol, 
HTTP status, 
bytes sent
```

But I am not getting last field about browser which is given in bracket.

**Can anyone explain this?**

I want specially the fields in brackets, i.e.

```
Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Better to see the documentation of the system where this log is generated.

Comment: I have seen it. I want specially bracket fields. For e.g., `Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)`

Comment: Usually it is called as ```user agent```.

Comment: I know it is user agent. But I want the information in bracket which is separated by semi colon.

Comment: I think this is what you are expecting. https://developers.whatismybrowser.com/useragents/explore/software_name/internet-explorer/5

Comment: But they have not explained it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last field you're interested in looks very much like the user agent (UA) information that web browsers and other HTTP clients send in the `User-Agent` HTTP request header (see e.g. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent), [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent), or the [HTTP 1.1 specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-5.5.3)).

> `Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)`

You asked about the portion of the user agent string inside parentheses. That is basically just a comment about the platform/system that the user agent is running on.

**In general,** I don't think that this string is required to be in any particular format (even though it might look similar for most common user agents) so be careful when attempting to parse this field.

From the HTTP 1.1 specification, [RFC 7231 section 5.5.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-5.5.3):

> ```
> User-Agent = product *( RWS ( product / comment ) )
> ```
>
> The `User-Agent` field-value consists of one or more product identifiers, each followed by zero or more comments (Section 3.2 of [RFC7230]), which together identify the user agent software and its significant subproducts. By convention, the product identifiers are listed in decreasing order of their significance for identifying the user agent software. Each product identifier consists of a name and optional version.

Regarding comments, see [RFC 7230 section 3.2.6](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.2.6):

> Comments can be included in some HTTP header fields by surrounding the comment text with parentheses.  Comments are only allowed in fields containing "comment" as part of their field value definition.

**More specifically,** [UserAgentString.com](http://useragentstring.com) keeps a detailed list of user agent strings and what they mean, see e.g. [here](http://useragentstring.com/pages/useragentstring.php?all=TRUE&name=Internet%20Explorer&vers=7.0) for ones similar to the one you're interested in. Here's a short example:

- `Mozilla/4.0` (product & product version outside parentheses): "Claims to be a Mozilla based user agent, which is only true for Gecko browsers like Firefox and Netscape. For all other user agents it means 'Mozilla-compatible'."

  (In case you're asking yourself why browsers self-identify as `Mozilla` even when they're something else, see e.g. [this other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1114254/why-do-all-browsers-user-agents-start-with-mozilla).)
- `compatible`: as above
- `MSIE 7.0`: the actual user agent (Internet Explorer 7)
- `Windows NT 5.1`: operating system version (Windows XP)
- `.NET CLR 2.0.50727`: .NET Framework 2 is installed on the client OS
- `.NET CLR 1.1.4322`: .NET Framework 1.1 is installed on the client OS

Comment: Re: _"the bracket fields are running on client's computer??"_ The user agent string is generated by a client, and transmitted to your web server as part (header) of a client's HTTP request. And the user agent string tells you something about that client.

Comment: Re: _"and how request is generated from two OS version i.e. 2.0 and 1.1"_ The .NET Framework (1.1, 2.0, etc.) is not an operating system. .NET Framework is a separate Windows subsystem, of which you can install several major versions (1.x, 2.x, 4.x) side-by-side. If you need more info specifically about what the .NET Framework is, I suggest you ask it as a separate question.

Comment: (sorry, by mistake called .NET as OS. I know about .NET.

Comment: I mean, particular request may be generated from one version of .NET. So asked. Here in bracket two .NET versions mentioned. So which shall we consider? (Yes, I might have asked the different question but as this subject talk is going on. so asking)

Comment: Whether you consider one, both, or none of these .NET CLR versions obviously depends on what you're trying to find out with your log analysis. I suggest you ask a new question about that, it's really quite a different matter from the question you originally asked. Answering a bunch of follow-up questions in the small print (comment section) isn't good practice here on SO, as it makes potentially valuable information harder to find for everyone else.