# Which web browser user agent strings do not begin with Mozilla or Opera?

Tags: browser, user-agent

As we know, ***not*** [all user agent strings begin with "Mozilla/"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1114254/why-do-all-browsers-user-agents-start-with-mozilla). Some begin with "Opera/". But are these two the only legitimate web browser [compatibility tokens](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent/Firefox), or are there other browsers that begin their user agent strings with other tokens?

---

*Note.*

I'm only looking for *unchanged* user agent strings of current *web browsers*, not "Dalvik" or the CFNetwork user agents ("Safari/"), not bots ("Twitterbot/") or other apps ("Wget/"), not whatever users may change their user agents to, etc. I'm also not looking for historic browsers like "Mosaic/".

Comment: https://pastebin.com/v8Az4yYk (first column - count, second - first part of UA) - list produced by this data: http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/useragentstring.php?name=All

Comment: @TarwirdurTuron Hmm, now all I have to do is find out which ones are browsers. And hope that data was complete... I especially like "Bimbot" ;-)

Comment: https://pastebin.com/uUR9f5hh I'm not sure that it is complete list. And I don't understand why you need such list..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may take a look [here](https://developers.whatismybrowser.com/useragents/explore/), where you can find a complete listing of Web Browser user agents sorted by:

- Software
- Operating Systems
- Operating Platforms
- Software types
- Hardware types
- Layout engines

If you goal is to list all legitimate web browser  "compatibility token", you may download the whole list as a MySQL DB ([here](https://developers.whatismybrowser.com/api/features/download-useragent-database)) then do query according to your need.

Comment: That's a bit of an indirect answer, and access to the database costs a $20 monthly subscription fee, but I guess it's the best answer I'm going to get...

Comment: Yep, sorry for the paid plan to get the DB... But, if it is very required you may pay one time only, get the DB, then stop you fee, in my opinion it is very low probable that a new web browser "compatibility token" will be release without you  know that

Answer (score 0):

A fairly complete and free list containing commonality as well.

https://developers.whatismybrowser.com/useragents/explore/software_type_specific/web-browser/2